# Amazon S3 Java SDK: Recursive copy from S3 to S3

Tags: java, amazon-s3, copy

Using the Java SDK for AWS S3, I need to copy every object under one s3 prefix to another s3 prefix, so that the files here in `$prefix_1`:

```
$prefix_1/key_remainder_1
$prefix_1/key_remainder_2
$prefix_1/key_remainder_3
```

are copied over to `$prefix_2`, which consequently looks like:

```
$prefix_2/key_remainder_1
$prefix_2/key_remainder_2
$prefix_2/key_remainder_3
```

Using the aws cli, I can use `aws s3 sync $bucket/$prefix1 $bucket/$prefix2` to accomplish this operation. From a glance, `sync` is essentially a LIST followed by a bunch of generated COPYs. However, the [java sdk](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3.html) doesn't seem to support an all-at-once approach (i.e. a single command/method like `sync`) to copying files from one prefix to another.

For whatever reason, `TransferManager` can bulk-copy between s3 and disk but not between s3 and s3.

Apparently, I either have to

1. explicitly `LIST` all objects under the prefix, then run a bunch of individual `COPY`s
2. use `TransferManager` to first download everything from the source prefix to disk, then upload the local directory to the destination prefix.

Have I missed something? Is there a way to get what I want using the java SDK?

Comment: I don't think you have missed anything.